# Raspbian 4.13 on Pi2 - Mouse issues

Tags: pi-2

Had model 2. just loaded the latest Raspbian 4.13. attached a wireless HP mouse. it is gliding on the screen, slow and behaving like it is drugged. this mouse works fine on other machines.

This is my first raspberry pi experience ever. Please advice how to make the mouse function normal.

looking forward.

Comment: `just loaded the latest Raspbian 4.13` - the latest is 4.14 for almost 3 weeks now

Comment: Have your tried a different mouse? Are you using the mouse on a somewhat porous surface?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you are going to find a solution. Most standard wireless USB HID devices (keyboards/mice) should just work out of the box. Occasionally there is one which won't, but looking for a different driver won't change anything unless the device is, e.g., an elaborate gaming mouse (in which case you may never find a driver, since most manufacturers do not provide one).

Unless the system is heavily taxed at the same time this happens (have a look at CPU usage in `top` or something), this sounds like radio interference. You could try replacing the batteries in the mouse with new ones. If they are already new, you are out of luck; you will have to try a different mouse.

Comment: thanks. but this mouse works fine on laptop and imac. so what could  be the issues?

Comment: It's probably not getting the amount of power it is used to.  Again, most such things work fine.  If it were an expensive item, I'd advise you do research before you buy something for use with the pi -- but there's not much point with USB mice.  You'll just find people saying how button 12 on their Acme XXL22 Megamouse doesn't work properly.  I know it may be some degree of hassle, but your best bet is to just try a $5-10 corded mouse -- or wireless, although they are obviously more prone to signal issues, most of them again should be fine.